# Compress tflite graph from 8mb to 2mb

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have following frozen inference graph [deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_tain](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5t7essIvKdfidQEdhsifLTDRmHfdmZr/view?usp=sharing). 
I got this graph from tensorflows [website](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md)
The size of this graph is 8.8mb. My task is to convert this graph to tflite format such that the size of tflite graph is 2 to 3mb.

I am using the following code to convert [deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_tain](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5t7essIvKdfidQEdhsifLTDRmHfdmZr/view?usp=sharing) graph to tflite:

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco \
   --input_file=deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_tain.pb \
   --output_file=output2/test.tflite \
   --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8  \
   --inference_type=FLOAT \
   --input_arrays=ImageTensor  \
   --output_arrays=SemanticPredictions  \
   --input_shapes=1,513,513,3 \
   --mean_values=128 \
   --std_dev_values=128
```

However,the output tflite-graph that I obtain is 8.5 MB in size. You can see the output graph [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wk8YmmtloNxUlhevB5pCs7DuMSv9vpMr/view?usp=sharing).

How do I compress this tflite-graph such that I get a graph of 2.7MB

To be more clear I want to obtain [this](https://github.com/dailystudio/ml/blob/master/deeplab/app/src/main/assets/deeplabv3_257_mv_gpu.tflite)  tflite graph by compressing [deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_tain.pb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5t7essIvKdfidQEdhsifLTDRmHfdmZr/view?usp=sharing) file

Comment: You can try post training quantize. Use the `post_training_quantize= True ` flag to quantize the high precision floats to 8 bit integers.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? could you test this on linked graph ? I am not getting required result using your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need not convert 8mb graph to 3mb,I found out that 3mb graph is already available here http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplabv3_mnv2_dm05_pascal_trainaug_2018_10_01.tar.gz